# How to give a name to the grouped items in sql with laravel db query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

with this code i get this output:

```
$q = DB::table('payments')
        ->join('agency', 'agency.id', '=', 'payments.agency')
        ->join('paymenttype','paypemttype.id', '=', 'payments.paymenttype')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(payment) as sum'), 'agency.agency', 'paymenttype.paymenttype')
        ->where('payments.school', '=', Sentry::getUser()->school)
        ->groupBy('payments.agency')
        ->groupBy('payments.paymenttype')
        ->get();
```

Output is:

```
[
{
sum: 200,
agency: "city1",
paymenttype: "credit card"
},
{
sum: 200,
agency: "city1",
paymenttype: "transfer"
},
{
sum: 200,
agency: "city2",
paymenttype: "credit card"
},
{
sum: 200,
agency: "city2",
paymenttype: "transfer"
}
  ]
```

But i want to that city will left hand side of table, so i want to this kind of output

```
-   city1  [
{
sum: 200,
paymenttype: "credit card"
},
{
sum: 200,
paymenttype: "transfer"
}],
- city2 [
{
sum: 200,
paymenttype: "credit card"
},
{
sum: 200,
paymenttype: "transfer"
}
  ]
```

So i mean object in object i want to get data like this kind. 
If you will help me, i will be so glad, thanks for helping again.

Comment: You probably need to select paymenttype column from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`keyBy`](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-keyby) method.

Since you're not using Eloquent, you can create a collection on your own.

Laravel 5:

```
$result = collect($q)->keyBy('agency');
```

Laravel 4:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$result = Collection::make($q)->keyBy('agency');
```

Comment: limonate by the way if i want to add a place to query then want to output like this, what must i do?   place1 ->[ { creditcard(or 1): 445 }, { transfer(or 2): 605 } ],  place2->[ { creditcard(or 1): 111}, { transfer(or 2): 212} ]

Comment: please update your question according this comment, I'm not sure I understant it correctly.

Comment: @yigitozmen unfortunately, it's still unclear for me. May be it will be better if you create new question with defined input and expected output.

Comment: @limonate i competly changed the question.

Comment: is it laravel 4 function?

Comment: @yigitozmen [yes](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_keyBy).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78807/discussion-between-limonte-and-yigitozmen).